# Errors when program is compiled

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have an assingment that im currently working on. To sum up when needs to be done (just to clarify im not asking anyone to do my assingnment, ive just ran into an issue i cant figure out) The method thats causing errors is deposit and this is its role(deposit method that deposits an amount to the account).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestBank {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bank bank = new Bank();

        bank.enterCustomers();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("==========================");
        System.out.println("Opening account balance");

        bank.printBalances();

        System.out.println();

        bank.banking();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("==========================");
        System.out.println("Closing account balance");
        bank.printBalances();
    }
}

class Bank {

    String accounts;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    Account account = new Account();

    public void enterCustomers() {

        ArrayList CustomerDetails = new ArrayList();

        while (true) {

            System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
            account.name = scanner.next();

            if (account.name.equals("q")) {

                break;

            } else {
                Input.promptText("Enter balance: ");
                account.balance = scanner.nextDouble();

                CustomerDetails.add(account.name);
                CustomerDetails.add(account.balance);

                System.out.println("Enter customer names or q to quit entering names");
            }
        }

        scanner.close();

    }

    public void printBalances() {

        System.out.println(account.name + " " + Math.round(account.balance * 100 / 100));

    }

    public void banking() {

        Account account = new Account();
        account.deposit();
        account.withdraw();

        int Newbalance = (int)(Math.round(account.balance));

        switch (Newbalance) {
            case 1:
                account.deposit();
                break;
            case 2:
                account.withdraw();
                break;
            case 0:
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    class Account {

        private String name;
        private double balance;

        public Account() {

            this.name = name;
            this.balance = balance;

        }

        public String getName() {

            return this.name;

        }

        public double getBalance() {

            return this.balance;

        }

        public double deposit() {


             Input.promptText("Enter a valid deposit: ");
             double amount = scanner.nextDouble();

            balance = balance + amount;

            Input.promptText("your balance after your deposit is: " + balance);
            return balance;

        }

        public double withdraw() {


              Input.promptText("Enter a valid withdraw: ");
           double amount = scanner.nextDouble();

            if (amount > balance); else {
            balance = balance - amount;
            }

            System.out.println("your balance after your withdrawal is: " + balance);
            return balance;
        }

    }

}

class Input {

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String getText() {
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public static String getText(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public static String getString() {
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public static String getString(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public static double getDouble() {
        return scanner.nextDouble();
    }

    public static double getDouble(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        return scanner.nextDouble();
    }

    public static void promptText(String text) {
        System.out.printf("%s", text);

    }

    public static void outputText(String text) {
        System.out.printf("%s\n", text);
    }

    public static void outputInteger(String text, int value) {
        System.out.printf("%s%d\n", text, value);
    }

    public static void outputDouble(String text, double value) {
        outputDouble(text, value, 2);
    }

    public static void outputDouble(String text, double value, int decimalPlaces) {
        System.out.printf("%s%." + decimalPlaces + "f\n", text, value);
    }

    public static void outputBoolean(String text, boolean value) {
        System.out.printf("%s%b\n", text, value);
    }
}
```

When i try to run the program the errors occur at line 130, which is 
"double amount = scanner.nextDouble();" and line 82 within the banking method which is  "account.deposit();"
 I believe its because account method has no parameterrs but i am unsure and would very much appreciate a nudge in the right direction

Comment: EDIT: I cant change the main

Comment: Do you get any message with error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
 at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1070)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1465)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at assignment1.Bank$Account.deposit(TestBank.java:130)
 at assignment1.Bank.banking(TestBank.java:82)
 at assignment1.TestBank.main(TestBank.java:28)
Enter a valid deposit: C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: it runs up to Enter Name: q

==========================
Opening account balance
q 0

Comment: basically you tried to use scanner which you have already closed in your enterCustomer method.

Comment: I asked for stack strace as ypu can understand from this scanner is closed. At wrong place may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Please check where you close scanner

scanner.close();

Comment: You are welcome, always make habit of checking each word in stack trace :)

Comment: so im still getting the issue, so i need to call scanner again after i close it? I need that close as a rquirement is to terminate the program once q is entered

Comment: the new issue is that i cant enter a name and a value. I can only exit the program @VedX

Comment: ah wait dont worry, i removed scanner.close(); and it works.

Comment: i have one more problem actually if you dont mind. When i run the deposit and withdraw method it doesnt use the original input. for example i get this